# How to update EF models created as "Code First from datebase"?

Tags: entity-framework

How to update EF models created as "Code First from datebase"?

I don't have a .edmx file (only a .cs one). How can I update it without deleting it and creating a new one ?

Comment: do you mean that you generated the models from the DB. If this is what you mean, then you need to install the power tools and re-generate from them. However, you should generate to a separate project in the solution so that it doesn't destroy anything you may have customised and then copy what you need from this project into the 'real' project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Entity framework code first approach you do not need .edmx file, instead you need to to define a class derived from **System.Data.Entity.DbContext** class.

Below is a sample class which works as Data repository.

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

Now when you update model classes. you need to first enable migrations using  **Enable-Migrations** command in Package Manager Console.
This command has added a **Migrations** folder to your project.

Now you need to run following command after making any changes in your model classes.

**Update-Database –Verbose** command in Package Manager Console.

This commaand will run migrations and update database accordingly.

For more details refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx